# CodeIgniter CSRF token in JSON request

Tags: json, codeigniter, csrf

I ran into an issue with CodeIgniter / CSRF / JSON.

I am sending http POST requests to my PHP backend with the Content-Type "application/json. The payload is JSON data. Along with the data, I pass the CSRF token that is generated and stored in the CSRF cookie. With a standard POST FORM request, it works just fine, but when sending as JSON it fails.

As $_POST array is empty because of the JSON content-type, CodeIgniter fails to validate the cookie and throws an error.

How can I have CodeIgniter check JSON payload and validate my CSRF token ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix that issue, I had to change the code of the "Security.php" file located in "system/core/".

In function "csrf_verify", replace that code:

```
// Do the tokens exist in both the _POST and _COOKIE arrays?
if ( ! isset($_POST[$this->_csrf_token_name], $_COOKIE[$this->_csrf_cookie_name]))
{
$this->csrf_show_error();
}
// Do the tokens match?
if ($_POST[$this->_csrf_token_name] != $_COOKIE[$this->_csrf_cookie_name])
{
$this->csrf_show_error();
}
```

By that code:

```
// Do the tokens exist in both the _POST and _COOKIE arrays?
if ( ! isset($_POST[$this->_csrf_token_name], $_COOKIE[$this->_csrf_cookie_name])) {
    // No token found in $_POST - checking JSON data
    $input_data = json_decode(trim(file_get_contents('php://input')), true); 
    if ((!$input_data || !isset($input_data[$this->_csrf_token_name], $_COOKIE[$this->_csrf_cookie_name])))
        $this->csrf_show_error(); // Nothing found
    else {
        // Do the tokens match?
        if ($input_data[$this->_csrf_token_name] != $_COOKIE[$this->_csrf_cookie_name])
            $this->csrf_show_error();
    }
}
else {
    // Do the tokens match?
    if ($_POST[$this->_csrf_token_name] != $_COOKIE[$this->_csrf_cookie_name])
        $this->csrf_show_error();
}
```

That code first checks $_POST then if nothing has been found, it checks the JSON payload.

The ideal way of doing this would be to check the incoming request Content-Type header value. But surprisingly, it's not straight forward to do ...

If someone has a better solution, please post it here.

Cheers

Comment: It would be best to do this by extending the Security library, rather than modifying the core file directly in system/core.  Create My_Security.php in application/core and override csrf_verify().  More about how to do this here: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can skip the CSRF checking by adding following code on application/config/config.php below Line No. 351 (based on CI 2.1.4).

```
 $config['csrf_expire'] = 7200; // This is line no. 351

/* If the REQUEST_URI has method is POST and requesting the API url,
    then skip CSRF check, otherwise don't do. */
if (isset($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]) &&
   (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) && ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') ))
{
    if (stripos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'/api/') === false )  { // Verify if POST Request is not for API
        $config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
    }
    else {
        $config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
    }
} else {
    $config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this needs to be overridden, best to extend the Security library rather than editing the core file directly.

Create the file My_Security.php in application/core/ and add the following (from the solution above):

```
<?php
class My_Security extends CI_Security {
    /**
     * Verify Cross Site Request Forgery Protection
     *
     * @return  object
     */
    public function csrf_verify()
    {
        // If it's not a POST request we will set the CSRF cookie
        if (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) !== 'POST')
        {
            return $this->csrf_set_cookie();
        }

        // Do the tokens exist in both the _POST and _COOKIE arrays?
        if ( ! isset($_POST[$this->_csrf_token_name], $_COOKIE[$this->_csrf_cookie_name])) {
            // No token found in $_POST - checking JSON data
            $input_data = json_decode(trim(file_get_contents('php://input')), true);
            if ((!$input_data || !isset($input_data[$this->_csrf_token_name], $_COOKIE[$this->_csrf_cookie_name])))
                $this->csrf_show_error(); // Nothing found
            else {
                // Do the tokens match?
                if ($input_data[$this->_csrf_token_name] != $_COOKIE[$this->_csrf_cookie_name])
                    $this->csrf_show_error();
            }
        }
        else {
            // Do the tokens match?
            if ($_POST[$this->_csrf_token_name] != $_COOKIE[$this->_csrf_cookie_name])
                $this->csrf_show_error();
        }        // We kill this since we're done and we don't want to

        // polute the _POST array
        unset($_POST[$this->_csrf_token_name]);

        // Nothing should last forever
        unset($_COOKIE[$this->_csrf_cookie_name]);
        $this->_csrf_set_hash();
        $this->csrf_set_cookie();

        log_message('debug', 'CSRF token verified');

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Brian write, you have to put your custom class into /application/core/ ex. My_Security.php

This is mine solution, work for me, i check the application/json content_type and request cookies.

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Security extends  CI_Security {


    public function csrf_verify()
    {

        // If it's not a POST request we will set the CSRF cookie
        if (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) !== 'POST')
        {
            return $this->csrf_set_cookie();
        }

                /**
                 *  mine implementation for application/json
                 */
                $reqHeaders = getallheaders();
                $content_type = $reqHeaders["Content-Type"];

                #it's a json request?
                if(preg_match("/(application\/json)/i",$content_type))
                {
                    #the check the cookie from request
                    $reqCookies = explode("; ",$reqHeaders["Cookie"]);
                    foreach($reqCookies as $c)
                    {
                        if(preg_match("/(".$this->_csrf_cookie_name."\=)/", $c))
                        {
                          $c = explode("=",$c);

                          if($_COOKIE[$this->_csrf_cookie_name] == $c[1])
                          {
                             return $this; 
                          }
                        }
                    }

                }
                //< end

        // Check if URI has been whitelisted from CSRF checks
        if ($exclude_uris = config_item('csrf_exclude_uris'))
        {
            $uri = load_class('URI', 'core');
            foreach ($exclude_uris as $excluded)
            {
                if (preg_match('#^'.$excluded.'$#i'.(UTF8_ENABLED ? 'u' : ''), $uri->uri_string()))
                {
                    return $this;
                }
            }
        }

        // Do the tokens exist in both the _POST and _COOKIE arrays?
        if ( ! isset($_POST[$this->_csrf_token_name], $_COOKIE[$this->_csrf_cookie_name])
            OR $_POST[$this->_csrf_token_name] !== $_COOKIE[$this->_csrf_cookie_name]) // Do the tokens match?
        {
            $this->csrf_show_error();
        }

        // We kill this since we're done and we don't want to polute the _POST array
        unset($_POST[$this->_csrf_token_name]);

        // Regenerate on every submission?
        if (config_item('csrf_regenerate'))
        {
            // Nothing should last forever
            unset($_COOKIE[$this->_csrf_cookie_name]);
            $this->_csrf_hash = NULL;
        }

        $this->_csrf_set_hash();
        $this->csrf_set_cookie();

        log_message('info', 'CSRF token verified');
        return $this;
    }

}
```