# CodeIgniter form only posting hidden fields

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, input, field

I have a CodeIgniter form that is only submitting hidden form fields, not text inputs and textareas.

The form:

```
<form action="/test.php" method="post" id="add_greeting_form" name="add_greeting_form">

    <label for="greeting_caption">Your caption:</label>
    <textarea id="greeting_caption" rows="3" cols="40" name="greeting_caption"></textarea>

    <label for="greeting_name">Created by:</label>
    <input name="greeting_name" id="greeting_name" type="text" size="16" maxlength="32" value="<?php echo $url_name; ?>">

    <label for="greeting_company">Company:</label>
    <input name="greeting_company" id="greeting_company" type="text" size="16" maxlength="32">

    <input type="hidden" name="json_decorations" id="json_decorations" value="" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="greeting_background" id="greeting_background" value="ninth_street" required>
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>" value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>">

    <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

Test.php **(entire file)**:

```
<?php
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
    echo $key.' = '.$value.'<br />';
}

// produces
// json_decorations = {"images":    [{"id":"big_house","src":"/images/2013/houses/townhouse.png","width":144,"height":323,"top":270,"left":566,"rotation":0},{"id":"clone_1","src":"/images/2013/decorations/cat.png","width":113,"height":86,"top":355,"left":374,"rotation":0}]}
// greeting_background = ninth_street
// csrf_test_name = 3c99b581bac9f07ba47ed7438b240b2b

?>
```

Output of test.php; only shows POST data for the hidden form fields (json_decorations and greeting_background):

When I submit to a controller with $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE), only the hidden form fields are listed in the POST data.

Comment: 1) check how the request you send looks exactly (using FireBug for example) - if the variables are missing, that means some JS code is cutting them before submitting
2) check if there is any `unset($_POST[...` in PHP code

Comment: FireBug only shows the hidden inputs. There aren't any unsets in the PHP. I'm not using AJAX.

Comment: If you turn off the profiler and use `echo '<pre>'.print_r($_POST, true).'</pre>';` or `echo '<pre>'.print_r($this->input->post(), true).'</pre>';` then do you get the same results?

Comment: maybe multipart form data tag?

Comment: Hm, why you are using required on hidden field? It doesn't make sense. What version of html you use? Isn't right to use input type submit instead button type submit?

Comment: You might be having this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798898/codeigniter-csrf-token-in-json-request

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness to rule out any sort of browser behavior, make sure your input elements are valid, put /> at the end

Comment: I'm using HTML5. Saving the form as a static HTML page work with all the fields' data in POST.